# PHP array_rand function get repeat result

Tags: php

I test php array_rand function and find it has repeat result ,this is my code:

```
    $arr = range(1,10000);
    $max = 200;
    $time = 0;
    while($time < $max){
        echo array_rand($arr).'<br>';
        $time++;
    }
```

And this is result:

[image]

You can see it keeps output repeat array index, and I am confused why it works like this, it is supposed to pick a random index.

Comment: Running the same code for me produces truly random data: https://3v4l.org/t8bCd. You must have something else interfering.

Comment: I didn't have any repeating number either, but provided an answer that might work for you.

Comment: In 10000, you want to get 200 is not so good(large amount for that range) !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use while ! `array_rand` accept max random keys number as second parameter .

```
$arr = range(1,10000);
$max = 200;
$ran = array_rand($arr,$max);
var_dump($ran); // random keys
//tested with origin array $arr
//foreach($ran as $key) {
//    echo $arr[$key]."<br>"; 
//}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make sure they don't repeat by doing something like this:

```
$arr = range(1,10000);
$max = 30;
$time = 0;
$used = array();
while($time < $max){
    $num = array_rand($arr);
    if( ! in_array($num, $used) ){
        echo $num . '<br>';
        $used[] = $num;
        $time++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because random values are not unique. Unless you really have to use numbers between 1 and 10,000, why not consider the following functions to get unique ids?

```
$number_and_letters = uniqid(); 
OR 
$numbers_only = hexdec(uniqid());
```

Hope it helps!